# Consecutive ListViews

Tags: android

I'm looking to gather user input from a series of ListViews. I need to store selections until the end of the series, at which point I'll put them into an SQLiteDb.

Is there a better way than, `startActivityForResult(listView1)`, make selection, `onActivityResult { save selection, startActivityForResult(listView2) }`, etc... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that this all be one activity, using either a single `ListView` (replacing the adapter each time), or perhaps a `ViewFlipper` holding your `ListViews`. Manage the BACK button yourself.

At the risk of quoting myself, from [Pattern "One activity, multiple views": Advantages and disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757418/pattern-one-activity-multiple-views-advantages-and-disadvantages/4758715#4758715) :

> Coase's "nature of the firm" theory
>   says that businesses expand until the
>   transaction costs for doing things
>   internally become higher than the
>   transaction costs for having other
>   firms do the same things.
>
> Murphy's "nature of the activity"
>   theory says that the activity expands
>   until the transaction costs of doing
>   things internally become higher than
>   the transaction costs for having other
>   activities do the same things. Android
>   developers will tend towards a "user
>   transaction" model for activities --
>   things that are tightly coupled (e.g.,
>   steps in a wizard) will tend to be
>   handled in single activity, and things
>   that have little relationship (e.g.,
>   browse vs. search vs. settings vs.
>   help vs. about) will tend to be
>   handled in distinct activities.

Your case sounds too tightly coupled for independent activities -- more like a wizard -- and so that's why I recommend doing it all in one.