# When should I create a new activity?

Tags: java, android

When should a new activity be created in android? Should I create a new activity for each large task or just switch views? What's best practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pattern one activity, multiple views. Advantages and disadvantages.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757418/pattern-one-activity-multiple-views-advantages-and-disadvantages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, whenever you would expect the back button to reverse the operation, start a new Activity.

The reason why there are 100s of questions on Stack Overflow asking how to override the back button is that developers often do not take this approach, then have to dig themselves out of the resulting mess.

Answer (score 2):

An activity represents a separate screen in android. Create an activity when you plan to go to a new screen.