# Is it ok to use setContentView() once in OnResume()

Tags: android

I have heard things about how it is bad to use `setContentView()`

[Pattern "One activity, multiple views": Advantages and disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757418/pattern-one-activity-multiple-views-advantages-and-disadvantages/4758715#4758715)

However I was wondering, would it be unlikely that my application will cause memory leaks, if I use `setContentView()` once in the `onResume()` method of my activity?

Whenever the user opens my app, it checks to see if something has been enabled in settings. If it has been enabled then the app uses a different screen compared to the original screen.

Therefor my code looks like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       String list = im.getEnabledInputMethodList().toString();
       if(Stuff is true){
        setContentView(R.layout.activityscreen_enabled);
       }
   }

}
```

Would using `setContentView()` be unlikely to cause memory leaks and other such problems? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing Android since few years now and I have never done that because I like to stick to the pattern which is almost always having the `setContentView` in the `onCreate`.

However, I do not believe that you would have big troubles doing that (for the memory leaks I mean).

Nevertheless, I do not see the point of doing such a thing, the pattern of the `Activity` (or how I understood it) is more:

> I create a view in the `onCreate` and I update its data in the `onResume` and if the data are A then add/remove this view and if the data are B add/remove this other view.

To be complete, I read your (really good) link and I think you maybe misunderstood how you can apply what Commonsware is saying: you can have multiply views without having different `setContentView`: your view structure needs, in this case, to be really modular and you will be able to load all the subviews dynamically (or, at least, it's how my colleague and I are doing ;) ).

For your example, I would have an empty layout for the base of the activity (let's say a blue background) and then for every view I want to have (every case), I would have a dynamic layout that I load at some point in the life cycle (probably at `onResume`). I do not believe that what you're doing is particularly bad but I doubt that it was thought like this ^^

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22228157/2545832) agrees with me

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple screens use a `Fragment` or even create a new `Activity` inside of messing around with the view for some reasons

- It's not good to have single `Activity` for the whole app or it will be so long and complicated.
- Your `onResume()` would need to handle the new views and their ids, onClickListeners... etc.
- `onResume()` is called many times unlike `onCreate()` so it would be a waste of time and memory to load the views over and over.
- According to android doc in activity life cycle about `onPause()` and `onResume()`

> Because this state can transition often, the code in these two methods should be fairly lightweight in order to avoid slow transitions that make the user wait.